# My Deno app can't download dependencies on my Ubuntu 22.04 server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, deno

I've been building a web application using Deno and Fresh my app works fine on my computer but when I deploy it to my Ubuntu 22.04 server I get this error

```
error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@0.193.0/dotenv/load.ts' failed: error sending request for url (https://deno.land/std@0.193.0/dotenv/load.ts): error trying to connect: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
    at file:///home/hyse.ch/main.ts:7:8
```

My best guess is that it might be a SSL certificate problem, though I tried to renew it but it still doesn't work.

What I'm using:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Deno 1.37.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
- v8 11.8.172.13
- TypeScript 5.2.2

I'm not really that good with server/linux stuff, I'm more into programming so let me know if you need anymore more details.

I've tried changing my SSL certificate it thought it would make it work.

Comment: See the GitHub issue [denoland/deno#6197](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6197) and the issues query view for [`"connection reset by peer"`](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22connection+reset+by+peer%22) — there are some reported issues with TLS flakiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me finding a solution and it turned out that deno.land had trouble accepting ipv6.